# copy pandas dataframe to postgresql with sqlalchemy results in 502 bad gateway error

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a postgresql table from a django form. I am accessing the table, modifying the table and then saving the changes inside of the table. the table has about 100k rows. I tried using `df.to_sql` but it is so slow that it results in `502 bad gateway` errors.

After looking around on sqalchemy doc and stackoverflow, I built this:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@ip_address/db',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

conn = engine.connect()
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
histoo = sqlalchemy.Table('uploadfiles_histoo', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = sqlalchemy.select([histoo])
resultproxy = conn.execute(query)
result_set = resultproxy.fetchall()
        
    
histoo = pd.DataFrame(result_set)
histoo.columns = result_set[0].keys()
        
data_initial = data_initial.append(histoo)
histo2 = pd.DataFrame(data_initial['Id'])


histo2[:0].to_sql('uploadfiles_histoo', engine, if_exists='replace')

            
output = io.StringIO()
histo2.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, encoding='utf8')
output.seek(0)

           
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.copy_from(output, 'uploadfiles_histoo', sep='\t', null='')
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

when I run this code, it is still resulting in `502 bad gateway` which means that I must have done something wrong and it does not improve the performance of the import. I am really struggling to understand what could be wrong, especially knowing that the script does not output an error linked to it. I am out of things that I could try, hopefully someone can spot where I am wrong here

UPDATE: I figured out that for python 3, `cStringI0` is just `io.StringIO` as well as writing like this:

```
histo2db = histo2.to_sql('uploadfiles_histoo', engine, if_exists='replace', header=False, method='multi',chunksize='5000')
```

I am starting to think the issue could come from the fact there could be an issue with accessing a table, reading from it and then modifying it from the same connection? I cannot find much online on that topic. Any help on this is more than welcomed

Comment: I have no problem in writing 250k lines with `df.to_sql()` method to a postgres table using it as follows: `df.to_sql('table_name', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace', schema='dev', method='multi', chunksize = 10000)` and its quite fast, 250k rows takes about 30 seconds for me.

Comment: I'll try it out with chunksize, but my script is already computing heavy, so I try to save every second that I can. Do you find something wrong in my code?